# AJAX Post to download file using MVC

Tags: .net, ajax, model-view-controller, response

I have to do this because the page I'm working with already has a `<form>` submission in the area, so I need to use AJAX to get around of the `<form> within a <form>` problem.

The problem is that my file is not being sent to the web page, my page gets a 200 OK response status but no file is sent.

**AJAX call on Responses.vbhtml:**

```
function exportCsv()
    {
    var formExportSettings = new Object();
    var responseIdsList = [];
    formExportSettings.formId = '@Model.form.formId.ToString()';
    formExportSettings.exporttype = 'csv';
    formExportSettings.format = $('input[name=export-format]:checked').val();
    formExportSettings.startDate = $('input[id=exportstartdate]').val();
    formExportSettings.endDate = $('input[id=exportenddate]').val();

    $('input[name=responseId]:checked').map(function() {
        responseIdsList.push($(this).val());
    });

    formExportSettings.responseIds = responseIdsList;
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(formExportSettings);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Forms/ExportCsv',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (success) {
                // never get the success message
                var message = success;
                console.log(message);
            }
        });
    }
```

**MVC controller action:**

```
   Function ExportCSV(model As FormsExportSettings) As ActionResult
        Dim exportModel As FormsExportModel = New FormsExportModel(model)

        Try
            Dim fileName = exportModel.form.formName + ".csv"

            Response.Clear()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & fileName)
            Response.BinaryWrite(exportModel.writer.ExportToBytes())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function
```

The `writer` in the above section (`exportModel.writer.ExportToBytes()`) is of type `CsvExport()` which exports my Csv as raw UTF8 bytes.

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that i receiving the CSV file as a `Response`. In Chrome, i can pull up the dev console, go to Network, and view the Response and i see the text of the CSV file. It is just not giving me the option to save it.

Comment: MVC + jQuery example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21464346/423430

Comment: This seems helpful but it looks like it is not using the standard .ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing the response directly, I would try something like this:

```
Function ExportCSV(model As FormsExportSettings) As FileContentResult
        Dim exportModel As FormsExportModel = New FormsExportModel(model)

        Dim fileName = exportModel.form.formName + ".csv"

        Return File(exportModel.writer.ExportToBytes(), "text/csv", fileName)       
End Function
```

The File function will handle all of the setting of the headers and the response and will return the file for download.

Comment: I've tried this method also and it gives me the same results as the OP